# individual value in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am running a loop:

```
$array = $_POST['d'];

foreach($array as $a){
    print_r($a);
}
```

$array contains the array (the number of array varies)
and i get this as a result. I just want to know how i can call these values individually in the loop. for example: $thing = value of methv in the loop

```
Array ( 
   [1173627548] => Array ( 
     [num] => 1173627548 
     [methv] => dont know 
     [q1] => - 
     [q2] => - 
     [q3] => U 
     [q4] => - 
     [comm] => 
    ) 
)
```

Sorry if i am unclear

print_r($array) show this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1173627548] => Array ( [num] => 1173627548 [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [1182868902] => Array ( [num] => 1182868902 [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [1173627548] => Array ( [num] => 1173627548 [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [1182868902] => Array ( [num] => 1182868902 [methv] => dont know [q1] => - [q2] => - [q3] => U [q4] => - [comm] => ) ) )
```

Note: I now have 2 arrays in this array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to loop on array `$a`, each one of whose elements are also arrays.

When you loop $array there is one item whose info is the one you said:

```
Array ( 
   [1173627548] => Array ( 
     [num] => 1173627548 
     [methv] => dont know 
     [q1] => - 
     [q2] => - 
     [q3] => U 
     [q4] => - 
     [comm] => 
    ) 
)
```

If you want to access `methv` element you should do the following:

```
foreach($array as $a){
    echo $a["methv"]; // this would access $array[ 1173627548 ][ "methv" ]
}
```

While the foreach continues you will keep accessing to all `$array[ ][ "methv" ]` values
Hope it helps.

---

**Based on your comment indicating the `print_r($array)`.**

First of all, let me indent it so that we get a better overview of the array:

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
    [1173627548] => Array ( 
        [num] => 1173627548 
        [methv] => dont know 
        [q1] => - 
        [q2] => - 
        [q3] => U 
        [q4] => - 
        [comm] => 
        )
      )
    [1] => Array ( 
     [1182868902] => Array ( 
        [num] => 1182868902 
        [methv] => dont know 
        [q1] => - 
        [q2] => - 
        [q3] => U 
        [q4] => - 
        [comm] => )
        )
)
 Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [1173627548] => Array ( 
        [num] => 1173627548 
        [methv] => dont know 
        [q1] => - 
        [q2] => - 
        [q3] => U 
        [q4] => - [comm] => 
        )
     )
    [1] => Array (
     [1182868902] => Array (
        [num] => 1182868902 
        [methv] => dont know 
        [q1] => - 
        [q2] => - 
        [q3] => U 
        [q4] => -
        [comm] => 
        )
    )
)
```

I guess you are printing it twice, because we can see two exactly arrays one after the other.

If you want to get `[methv]` item, what you need is to access:

```
$array[ 0 ][ 1173627548 ][ "methv" ]
$array[ 1 ][ 1182868902 ][ "methv" ]
```

So what you can do is to use `foreach` twice:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        echo $v[ "methv" ];
    }
}
```

Comment: hey mate thanks for replying i have just tried this and i get a undefined index. Any other ideas? thanks

Comment: Please show `print_r($array)` so that we can know whether you posted `print_r($array)` or `print_r($array[1173627548])`

Comment: edited sorry for the late reply

Comment: Good to read that, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, I would suggest some crude but readable debugging, like this:

```
function trace($a) { print "<pre>".var_export($a, 1)."</pre>"; }
// then you can do:
trace($array);
```

As for your question, you can access the methv key like this: `$array[0][1173627548]['methv']` (or `$array[1173627548]['methv']` if the above trace is the full $array variable).

Comment: hey dude thanks for replying, i there would be more values in the array with different numbers. is there any other way to call it?